# Displaying a menu's child links

Tags: 7, routes

It seems that, by default, Omega, and other themes do not render [child links](http://drupal.org/node/1018698#comment-4778132).

I have tried various modules (e.g. Superfish, and Megamenu), but they do not offer a structure that allows me to theme to the design I am after.

I found [this page](http://drupal.org/node/1018698#comment-5720702), but it does not seem to use `theme_links()`.

Is there a simple way to enable all my menu links, and still be able to hook into it before they are rendered?

Comment: `hook_links()` is not a Drupal 7 hook.

Comment: My bad [theme_links()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21theme.inc/function/theme_links/7)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer lies in how and where [menu_tree_page_data](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!menu.inc/function/menu_tree_page_data/7) is being [called](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!menu.inc/function/calls/menu_tree_page_data/7).

For the navigation, Drupal will call *menu_tree_page_data* via [menu_navigation_links](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!menu.inc/function/menu_navigation_links/7) which will only return a single level of links. You can follow this function up to [menu_main_menu](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!menu.inc/function/menu_main_menu/7) and then [template_preprocess_page](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_page/7) before it (which is how it ends up as a variable in page.tpl.php)

However, if you insert a menu as a block *menu_tree_page_data* is called by [menu_tree](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!menu.inc/function/menu_tree/7) (which calls [menu_tree_output](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!menu.inc/function/menu_tree_output/7) immediately after which does some additional work to the array for the final markup.) After both have run you have your whole menu tree available as an array which I then ran through some custom PHP code to loop through the array and render it into an HTML list.

p.s. I also did not use any of Drupal's default menus. I created my own because I needed control of how my mark up was built (and because I had trouble getting control of the 'links' hook to use with theme_menu_link.) I defined my own theme hook ("THE_MENU_NAME") corresponding to my menu name and also my own theme template which is where I did all my markup building before rendering.

<strike>theme('links__system_main_menu', array('links' => $main_menu, 'attributes' => array('id' => 'main-menu', 'class' => array('links', 'inline', 'clearfix', 'main-menu')), 'heading' => array('text' => t('Main menu'),'level' => 'h2','class' => array('element-invisible'))));</strike>

```
theme('THE_MENU_NAME', array('menu_tree' => $menu_tree));
```

I hope this helps some people out there.

Answer (score 2):

Go to your parent menu item, edit it and click on the 'Show as expanded' checkbox. Now all the children menu items should be visible from the top level.

Comment: All of them do have Show as expanded checked.